# How to delete a record from a table the table reference is in another table using hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I am newbie on Hibernate,
I want to perform deletion on one table the current table is referenced to another table.

### Ex: Client_Loan is my main table i want to perform deletion on this, and the another table is 'Loan_Details'. the loan_details table contains the foreign_Key reference to the client_loan id.

i want to perform delete on client_loan table, if i delete client loan table the references in another table also want to delete at one shot using Hibernate can any one tell me how to perform.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
You must be having classes like below

@Entity
@Table(name="Client_Loan")
public class ClientLoan {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        mappedBy = "client", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Loan_Details> loans = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Loan_Details> getComments() {
        return loans;
    }

    public void addComment(Loan_Details loan) {
        loans.add(loan);
    }

}

below for load details

@Entity
@Table(name="Loan_Details ")
public class LoanDetails {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Client_Loan client;

    public void setPost(Client_Loan post) {
        this.post = post;
    }

    public String getReview() {
        return review;
    }

    public void setReview(String review) {
        this.review = review;
    }
}

Now in ClientLoan in OnetoMany mapping cascade = CascadeType.ALL
it means when you will delete CleintLoan all the LoanDetails will be deleted automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete from Loan_Details then Client_loan

```js
First delete from Loan_Details then Client_loan

int id = 2;
Session session=getSession();  
String hql = "delete from Loan_Details where client_loanid = :id"; 
session.createQuery(hql).setString("id", new Integer(id)).executeUpdate();

hql = "delete from Client_Loan where clientid = :id"; 
session.createQuery(hql).setString("id", new Integer(id)).executeUpdate();
```